# How Can i publish a asp.net(c#) website in a local system?

Tags: c#

Recently I create a website in c#.net. But I don't want to host in net. can I publish it in a LAN? If it is possible? How can I make it? Please help me.....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you trying doing it ? If not please give it a try and come back if you are facing any issues. There are lot of info available on how to deploy apps in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Run a webserver on a computer on your lan and host the files there.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_install.asp

Answer (score 0):

For this projects you can run it on IIS on your own computer and publish it on you LAN.

This is a good point to start with.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323972

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771124(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To publish website first we need to check whether IIS installed in our local machine or not.

You can use this site

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/publish-or-deploy-website-in-our-local.html